# $S$ is a non empty set and there are $a$ and $b$ for $c$ and $d$ such that $a\cdot c = d$ and $c\cdot b = d$, prove it is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

An associative operation $\cdot \ $was defined in $S$ such that $\cdot \ $is associative. Also, for all the pairs $c$ and $d$, there are elements $a$ and $b$ such that:

$$a\cdot c = d, \ \ \ \ c\cdot b = d$$

I need to show that $(S,\cdot)$ form a group.

At first I tougth it was all about constructing the Cayley tables for the group, but then I started thinking about it and now I think it's all about proving that the $4$ group axioms are valid in this set. But there's no mention about the existence of inverses, and I don't think there is a way to prove it. Anybody cal help?

Comment: Hint: first show that there exists an identity by setting $c=d$. Then show existence of inverses by setting $d=e$ ($e$ is this identity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take an element $a$, find $e$ so that $ae=a$. Every other element $b$ of $S$ is of the form $ca$ and so $be=(ca)e=c(ae)=ca=b$ and so $e$ is right identity.

Use same argument to find $e'$ so that $e'$ is left identity.

We have $e=e'e=e'$ and so $e$ is identity.

Given $a$ we have $b$ and $c$ so that $ba=e$ and $ac=e$. Now notice $c=ec=(ba)c=b(ac)=be=b$

So $b$ is inverse.